# Transformation of List[(Object1,Object2)] to Map[Object1, List[Object2]] - Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I have a list of pairs of objects Object1 and Object2.

I want to transform this list into a Map[Object1, List[Object2]].

Until now I implemented this one:

```
dictionary map (w => (wordOccurrences(w), w))
 groupBy(identity).mapValues(_._2).toMap
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `mapValues` are `List`s. You need to traverse each `List` in order to un-tuple each element.

You'll also need to isolate the key, "Object1", from each tuple.

No `toMap` required. `groupBy` produces a `Map` already.

```
...groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way is to use map/case. Note the curly brackets:

```
val plist = List((1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9))
plist.toMap map {case (a, b) => (a -> List (b))}
```